# How to set up vpn tunnel (ipsec) connection

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

I'm working with a client who wants to set up a vpn tunnel between their network and ours.
They're in charge of the tunnel and to give us the access they are asking me my public IP and my LAN IP.

This is what i've got when i do an ifconfig on the server i will use to connect to the vpn

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:cd:xx:xx  
          inet adr:62.210.xxx.xxx  Bcast:62.210.xxx.xxx  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::d6ae:52ff:xxxx:xx/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:55255032 erreurs:0 :779628 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5419527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:5598164393 (5.5 GB) Octets transmis:1034297288 (1.0 GB)
          Interruption:16 Mémoire:c0000000-c0012800 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:45923382 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45923382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0
```

The `inet adr:62.210.xxx.xxx` is my public IP but it seems like i dont have any LAN IP.

Can the connection work without LAN IP or should I create a private network somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's IPsec tunnel then you should have local IP as well, because it's how decision about encryption of traffic has been made by IPsec.

You can add one more network card to this server, where local network will be configured.

Comment: Can i add a virtual interface? I can't add a network card.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve and how you see it working in your network.

If you have multiple users sitting behind NAT than it's better way to add one more network card to this server. If you want specific app to work on this server with IPsec than you can add virtual interface and manipulate with iptables and routing.